# MongoDB - How to declare object variable in jstl

Tags: spring-mvc, jstl

I'm using MongoDB, My object is like this

```
{ 
    "id" : "1", 
    "Name" : "jack", 
    "Date" : "22-03-2018", 
    "Time" : "123412", 
    "tmax_volumes" : {
        "type1" : "392.7cm", 
        "type2" : "83.1cm", 
        "type3" : "24.1cm", 
        "type4" : "15.6cm"
    }
}
```

Now want to print `tmax_volumes` in my `jstl` page.

In my jstl page using `${COLL.tmax_volumes}` this variable I'm getting `tmax_volumes` object, like this below

```
    { 
     "type1" : "392.7cm" , 
     "type2" : "83.1cm" , 
     "type3" : "24.1cm" , 
     "type4" : "15.6cm"
   }
```

Now I need to pring using Key `values`,

```
392.7cm
83.1cm
24.1cm
15.6cm
```

Thanks

Comment: how about using jstl like this `${COLL.tmax_volumes.type1}`?

Comment: What is the Java type of `tmax_volumes`?

Comment: @JasperdeVries type is String

Comment: OK, not ideal. See if you can convert that in your backend to a `Map<String,String>`, or else search for a custom tag to handle JSON strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my model, I map `tmax_volume` Object

```
private Map<String,String> tmax_volumes;
```

And my jstl page, I have assigned like this below

```
<p>${COLL.tmax_volumes.type1}</p>
<p>${COLL.tmax_volumes.type2}</p>
<p>${COLL.tmax_volumes.type3}</p>
<p>${COLL.tmax_volumes.type4}</p>
```